# Find column differences between tables with the same name in two different databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two databases, and both of them have the exact same table names. However, certain columns between the matching tables have been added and removed between the two databases. I am trying to figure out how to write a query that can return the columns only in the first database and columns only in the second database.

I have been using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, but I am stuck since I can't find a way to compare the INFORMATION_SCHEMA between two databases. I was hoping this syntax would work to differentiate the two databases, but it does not:

```
[Database1]..[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]
```

If you can tell by now, I am not too experienced with SQL

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As its name suggests, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is a schema.  Hence, the three part naming is:

```
from Database1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

You have two periods together, which suggests the default schema, but that is not where the views are.

You can use four-part naming if you want to access the views on another server.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will find any columns in DB1 that are NOT in DB2.

```
select t.name as TableName
    , c.name as ColumnName
from DB1.sys.tables t
join DB1.sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id

EXCEPT

select t.name as TableName
    , c.name as ColumnName
from DB2.sys.tables t
join DB2.sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id
```

You can simply reverse this to find columns in DB2 that are not in DB1.

Another option is to purchase a third party component like SQL Compare from RedGate.